# Instantiate child button with given value, but it is not changed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning new Dart/Flutter and try to make my own exercise. I believe I am missing something fundamental here.

**Problem:** 
My button is showing question mark. But I instantiate it with value already

**Question:**
How to instantiate button with given text?

```dart
import 'package:complete_guide/question.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'answer.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int index = 0;
  List<String> questions = [
    "How may I help you?",
    "What is you favorite dog?"
  ];

  void _answerQuestion(){
    setState(() {
      index = index + 1;
    });
    print(index);
  }

  void showText(inputText){
    print(inputText);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Stay Strong")
        ),
         body: Center(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               Question(questions[index]),
               Answer("iddqd", _answerQuestion),
               Answer("idkfa", _answerQuestion),
               Answer("show me the money", _answerQuestion),
             ],
           ),
         ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  String answerText = "?";

  Answer(answerText, this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      )
    );
  }
}


class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        this.questionText,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.orange),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *do not* ignore analyzer warnings. They are there for a reason.

First, `answerText` should be marked as final. It should not be initialized so that it can be assigned a value in the constructor. Finally, you need to use the `this.` syntax that you've used for all of your other constructor parameters.

There is also no need of providing a default value of `'?'` for `answerText` because the constructor uses it as a required parameter, so that default value will never be used.

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.answerText, this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My console does not give me any warning. How can I check that?

Comment: @Joe You should be using the Flutter and Dart extensions on whatever editor you're using.

Comment: Found it on editor and also `dart analyze` command line. Thank you very much.